# Why C# reflection throw this BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, reflection

Here is my application code. Just simple one. I'm new in C#. I tried other examples which work perfectly. But the exception "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." I have no clue why. Please let me know. Is there a way that the Core.dll won't allow loading dynamically and call by refection.

```
           Assembly asm = null;
            try
            {
                // Excepition in this line
                 asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\myproj\Core.dll");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            }

        MethodInfo staticMethodInfo = t.GetMethod("Create");
        if (staticMethodInfo == null)
        {

        }
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        staticMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { typeof(string), typeof(JObject), assemblies });
```

I get the following exception:-

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\myproj\Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'file:///C:\myproj\Core.dll'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\practice\csharp\MyApp\MyApp\Program.cs:line 61

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\myproj\Core.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/practice/csharp/MyApp/MyApp/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\practice\csharp\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/myproj/Core.dll.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\myproj\Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Comment: i would think `C:\myproj` would have some kind of file protections on it

Comment: Did you check that bitness of your application and Core.dll are compatible.

Comment: Where did Core.dll come from? Is it your own assembly? Are you certain it's actually a .NET assembly?

Comment: it is certainly a .NET application written in C#. It has many modules. It might have some unmanaged code as well.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to load 32bit aseembly from 64bit application or visa versa?

Comment: Both source code is compiled by myself in Win 10 by vs2015 in the same pc. For a requirement, I have to call one static API from PowerShell script.

Comment: Let me ask a slightly different question: Why are you using reflection to invoke this method? You should be able to reference the assembly and call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong:

> WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().

Your assembly is not a .NET *IL* assembly, and cannot be loaded as you're trying to load it. You need to use `Assembly.Load()` instead.

Comment: it is certainly a .NET application written in C#. It has many modules. It might have some unmanaged code as well.

Comment: @masiboo I'm talking specifically about this Core.dll you're trying to load. If Core.dll was run through a process called Native Image Generation (ngen) then it can't be loaded the way you're trying to load it. (Or if, for example, it's a C/C++ native assembly.)

Comment: It is mostly written in c#. But it has little unmanage code as well. In the case of ngen, how to load it and call one static method